# How do I build the mainline kernel with all default Ubuntu modules?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

My normal way of building a mainline kernel has been:

```
$ sudo apt build-dep linux
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
$ cd linux
$ make localmodconfig
$ make -j`nproc` deb-pkg
```

And off I go. However, I'd like to build a kernel that includes the same modules that a default Ubuntu install would include. the `make localmodconfig` only includes active modules, and I want all standard modules to handle future hardware. A lot is missing:

```
$ cd /lib/modules
$ find 4.20.15-042015-generic |wc -l
6401
$ find 5.0.0+ |wc -l
296
```

So what is the config command to mirror the standard distribution?